# Need to remove tasks from Scheduled Tasks from NSIS installer while uninstalling

Tags: scheduled-tasks, nsis

I have created an installer using [NSIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nullsoft_Scriptable_Install_System). Now I am facing an issue like my application can create a scheduled task, but when I am uninstalling it, it is not removing/deleting tasks that I have created from my application, and they are still visible in Schedule Tasks. And I am scheduling an Autorun task every time.

How do I delete an Autorun task from Schedule Tasks when I am uninstalling it?

Comment: How did you create the task?

Answer (score 1):

The best option is probably to just let your application do it; `ExecWait '"$instdir\myapp.exe" /uninstalltask'`

You could also execute at.exe/schtasks.exe with the [nsExec plugin](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/nsExec/nsExec.txt).

Calling the task scheduler API directly is complicated and there are two versions you need to deal with:

```
!include LogicLib.nsh
;V1:
!define CLSID_CTaskScheduler {148BD52A-A2AB-11CE-B11F-00AA00530503}
!define IID_ITaskScheduler {148BD527-A2AB-11CE-B11F-00AA00530503}
;V2:
!define CLSID_TaskScheduler {0F87369F-A4E5-4CFC-BD3E-73E6154572DD}
!define IID_ITaskService {2FABA4C7-4DA9-4013-9697-20CC3FD40F85}

RequestExecutionLevel Admin

!define MyTaskFolder "\"
!define MyTaskName "Test"
Section
System::Call "ole32::CoCreateInstance(g '${CLSID_TaskScheduler}', i 0, i 5, g '${IID_ITaskService}', *i.r1)i.r0"
${If} $0 = 0
    !define VARIANTBYVALPARAM_EMPTY "i0xcccc0000,i0xcccccccc,i0xcccccccc,i0xcccccccc"
    System::Call "$1->10(${VARIANTBYVALPARAM_EMPTY},${VARIANTBYVALPARAM_EMPTY},${VARIANTBYVALPARAM_EMPTY},${VARIANTBYVALPARAM_EMPTY})i.r0"
    ${If} $0 = 0
        System::Call '$1->7(w "${MyTaskFolder}", *i.r2)i.r0' ; ITaskService::GetFolder
        ${If} $0 = 0
            System::Call '$2->15(w "${MyTaskName}", i0)i.r0' ; ITaskFolder::DeleteTask
            System::Call 'kernel32::FormatMessage(i 0x00001000|0x00000100|0x00000200,i0,i$0,i0,*i.r9,i0,i0)'
            System::Call '*$9(&t${NSIS_MAX_STRLEN}.r3)'
            System::Call 'kernel32::LocalFree(i$9)'
            DetailPrint "ITaskFolder::DeleteTask HRESULT=$0 ($3)"
            System::Call '$2->2()' ; ITaskFolder::Release
        ${EndIf}
    ${EndIf}
    System::Call '$1->2()' ; ITaskService::Release
${EndIf}
${IfThen} $0 = 0 ${|} Goto done ${|}
System::Call "ole32::CoCreateInstance(g '${CLSID_CTaskScheduler}', i 0, i 5, g '${IID_ITaskScheduler}', *i.r1)i.r0"
${If} $0 = 0
    System::Call '$1->7(w "${MyTaskName}")i.r0' ; ITaskScheduler::Delete
    System::Call 'kernel32::FormatMessage(i 0x00001000|0x00000100|0x00000200,i0,i$0,i0,*i.r9,i0,i0)'
    System::Call '*$9(&t${NSIS_MAX_STRLEN}.r3)'
    System::Call 'kernel32::LocalFree(i$9)'
    DetailPrint " ITaskScheduler::Delete HRESULT=$0 ($3)"
    System::Call '$1->2()' ; ITaskScheduler::Release
${EndIf}
done:
SectionEnd
```